# How to Add a RadioButton dynamically with custom Width?

Tags: android, android-radiogroup

I would like to add a set of Radio buttons in an Android application dynamically. I added a RadioGroup in my Xml file :

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/sugg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Question"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/number"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Question"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp" >
 </RadioGroup>
```

I have a JsonArray which contains a list of responses that should be displayed as Radio buttons so the user can select only one choice . I was able to display the radio buttons but without a text.

This is how it is displayed : 
[image]

My Question is how to display the text ?

here is the function that I developed :

```
public void addRadioButtons(RadioGroup rad,JSONObject jObj){
    try {
        JSONArray answ=(JSONArray) jObj.get("Responses");
        for(int i=0;i<answ.length();i++){

            JSONObject an=(JSONObject) answ.get(i);
            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(c);

            radioButton.setLayoutParams (new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            radioButton.setId(i);
            radioButton.setText(an.getString("DescriptionEn"));
            radioButton.setWidth(200);
            rad.addView(radioButton);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I checked the radio button text value and it contained the text that I want to display but the width is always 0 and I was not able to change it .
I add this instruction `radioButton.setWidth(200);`

For the LayoutParams I used `import android.widget.RadioGroup.LayoutParams;`

Thank You.

Comment: Probably issue is related to color so try to set color for text :`radioButton.setTextColor(Color.RED)`

Comment: Thank You that was the solution , I tried to change the screen color at first but now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final Working Code (Takes JSON Object and RadioGroup as parameters):

```
public void addRadioButtons(RadioGroup rad,JSONObject jObj){
try {
    JSONArray answ=(JSONArray) jObj.get("Responses");
    for(int i=0;i<answ.length();i++){

        JSONObject an=(JSONObject) answ.get(i);
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(c);

        radioButton.setLayoutParams (new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        radioButton.setId(i);
        radioButton.setText(an.getString("DescriptionEn"));
        radioButton.setTextColor(Color.GREY)
        rad.addView(radioButton);

    }
} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}